# With df -h how to create custom alert-conditions

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk, linux-disk-free

With `df -h`, `awk`, `tail`, `tr`, how to create a custom "alert" column that should display one of the following indications for /mnt/hgfs :

- *Warning*: If the occupancy rate is between 75% and 80%
- *Critical*: If the occupancy rate is between 81% and 95%
- *Alarm*: If the rate is greater than 96%

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. What have you tried so far? Why do you mention awk, tail, tr? Are they required?

Comment: Thanks i want to use one those command i tried creating a column df - h | awk v observation =´´$observation) ’´

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Sorry, this is not the way StackOverflow works. Questions of the form "I want to do X, please give me tips and/or sample code" are considered off-topic. Please visit the [help] and read [ask], and especially read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)?

Comment: I suggest to start with `df -hP` and not `df -h`.

Comment: I want a custom "alert" column that should display one of the following indications for /mnt/hgfs : Warning: If the occupancy rate is between 75% and 80% Critical: If the occupancy rate is between 81% and 95% Alarm: If the rate is greater than 96

Answer (score -1, accepted):

*edit:* It's staying up.

```
df |awk -v threshold="75 81 96" -v message="Warning Critical Alarm" -v mnt="/mnt/hgfs" '
  BEGIN {n=split(threshold, T); split(message, M)}
  $NF == mnt {
    for(i=n; i>0; i--)
      if(int($5) > T[i]) {print M[i] ":", mnt, "usage:", $5; exit}
    print mnt, "usage normal"                                                                                                                                               
  }'
```

1. Import your arbitrary values as space-separated strings.
2. `split` lists into arrays; get the number of elements with `n=split()`
3. On any line whose last column is "/mnt/hgfs", `i`terate backwards over the T(hreshold) array, comparing the fifth column (Use%) to each value. If it's greater, print a warning message using the same value for the M(essage) array, then exit before other comparisons are performed.

Solution for new requirements:

```
df |awk '
  NR == 1      {alert="Alert"}
  int($5) < 75 {alert=""}
  int($5) > 75 {alert="Warning"}
  int($5) > 81 {alert="Critical"}
  int($5) > 96 {alert="Alarm"}
               {printf("%-10s%s\n", alert, $0)}'
```

Comment: I want to add this to a 7th column named ‘’ Observation ‘’

Comment: @JohnRudolph I will work with you on additional requirements if you accept this answer to your original requirements.

Comment: to create and add a custom  column titled "Alert"  shouldn’t it begin with df - h | awk -v alert ="($alert)" ?

Comment: @JohnRudolph I would add a line: `{printf("%-10s%s\n", foobar, $0)}` to always print a padded string to the left of the original output. Then you could simply change the value of foobar based on Use%.

Comment: @JohnRudolph I added a simple filter that checks the value of $5 repeatedly